# Output markup & controls dependent on result of Javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page which includes markup and 3rd party controls (in this particular case Telerik controls) e.g.

```
<h1>Hello</h1>

<telerik:RadToolBar ID="toolbarCAD" runat="server" Skin="Web20" Height="30px" Width="300px" OnClientButtonClicked="OnClientButtonClicked">
    <Items>
      <telerik:RadToolBarButton runat="server" Text="Zoom In" ImageUrl="~/images/zoom_in.png" Value="cadZoomIn">
                    </telerik:RadToolBarButton>
    </Items>
</telerik:RadToolBar>
```

I only want to display this if an ActiveX control is installed.  From another question I have a Javascript function (ActiveXOrNull) which successfully detects this so now I have replaced the above in my markup with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var obj = ActiveXOrNull('CADViewX');
    if (obj == null) {
        WHAT DO I DO HERE
    }
</script>
```

How do I include the original markup in the Javascript function?  Can I "include" another page or is there another method available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the control in a `<div>` tag

```
<div id="telerickControl">
    <telerik:RadToolBar.........
    </telerick:RadToolBar>
</div>
```

Then inside the javacript function you can put

```
    var obj = ActiveXOrNull('CADViewX');
    if (obj == null) {
        document.getElementById("telerickControl").style.display = "block";
    }
```

By Default, set the `div` to be `display: none` and then show it to the user if they have the ActiveX object.

This will hide the element of the page through the style property `display`. However, this will still render the control on the page, so the control will still be rendered.

**EDIT**

Updated answer suggested by Stilgar.

Comment: You should do it the other way around. Make it invisible in markup and enable it via JS. Otherwise the user will see it for a moment before the JS kicks in.